# GetItems from SPList case sensitive

Tags: caml, splist

I have troubles with `CAML Query` and `GetItems` method from `SPList`.

I get a `SPList` from web context:

```
SPList docTypeList = _web.GetList(string.Format("{0}{1}", web.ServerRelativeUrl, "DocumentType"));
```

The list contains multiple values.

I want to search in it only the value which has a field called `DocumentType` with the value **"MyValue1"**. (case sensitive)

I am using the CAML Query:

```
var queryBuilder = new CAMLQueryBuilder();
            queryBuilder.AddComparison("DocumentType", CAMLQueryBuilder.COMPARISON_TYPE.Eq, "MyValue1");

var query = new SPQuery { Query = queryBuilder.GenerateCAML() };
SPListItemCollection queryResultItems = docTypeList.GetItems(query);
```

In this case it returns as result a record which has the field **"DocumentType"** having the value **"myvalue1"**, it does not take care about string sensitive.

Is there a possibility to get Items considering sensitive cases?

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Possible DUPLICATE of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404270/caml-query-case-sensitive-search

Comment: It's all case insensitive, after getting the results, you'd need to iterate thru and do your own case sensitivity checking.

Comment: @Evariste -> thanks. It seems the query are case-insensitive, and it is necessary to filter the results.

Comment: @Eric -> you're right, thanks. Maybe you know, is there a simple way of iterating through items within the SPListItemCollection and extract item Fields values ?

Comment: The only way is to run your CAML query, get all results (case-insensitive) and process each of them in a `foreach` loop to check `item["DocumentType"]`against `"MyValue1"`(case-sensitive comparision with `string.Equals`).

Comment: Thanks friends! Can someone repost the comment as answer to mark the question answered please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Evariste and @Eric mentioned in comments:
**CAML Query is case-insensitive.**

The solution was to filter the results from

```
SPListItemCollection queryResultItems = docTypeList.GetItems(query);
```

and check for case-sensitive.

I created a small method which does this.

```
private SPListItem FindCaseSensitive(string documentType, IEnumerable items)
{
    SPListItem foundItem = null;
    if (items == null) return null;

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var spItem = item as SPListItem;
        if (spItem == null) continue;

        var propertyValue = spItem["DocumentType"];
        if (!propertyValue.ToString().Equals(documentType)) continue;

        foundItem = spItem;
        break;
    }
    return foundItem;
}
```